# How to reduce server response waiting time when sending requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, bots, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Im trying to create a arbitrage bot, so I need to query data faster than other bots. I tried all methods such as using aiohttp, multi-threading, multi-processing, but seems that my bot still slower than competitor. I realized that problem can be Waiting Server response time (it's cloudflare server). It takes 0.29s to complete a request. Is there anything I can do to optimize this waiting time ? I'm thinking about sending request directly to origin server not cloudflare server . Is it possible ?

Comment: In aiohttp, are you reusing a single session (that's a bit faster)? Is there a redirect? if its consistent, then you could just go to the redirected url. If you have access to this other bot, you could capture packets to see whether the raw wire to wire times are the same. If the server accepts multiple content types, one may be faster than another. And if you know the origin server and it accepts your requests, then you could skip the intermediate cloudfare server. The cloudflare server could be faster than the origin if it is also caching and happens to be "closer" on the network.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, Im reusing a single session, and there is no redirect url, just simply sending post request and return json content. I dont think origin server will accept my requests so I'm looking for another solution that can help me to optimize waiting server response time. I dont think my problem is sending requests time

Comment: Where you connect to the internet makes a difference. I'll have faster response time at work than at home. Better with a direct ethernet connection to the router verses wifi. You could put your bot on clouldflare. Or another cloud server that has a faster/fatter pipe.

Comment: Can you please give me some sugggestions that where can I put my bot on for better connect to cloudflare server ?